# I have excessive Tearing on Flash Video Playback when i don't use compiz , on ubuntu 12.04 i dont have tearing

Tags: flash, tearing

I have excessive Tearing on Flash Video Playback when i don't use compiz , on ubuntu 12.04 i dont have tearing but i dont want unity 3d cause i got less frames on my games + bad performance !!!!

I tested the tearing with 3 Nvidia graphics cards in 3 different pcs
The two of them had 
1) Nvidia gts-250
2) Nvidia 9400

Both had tearing on:
1) ubuntu 12.04 unity 2d
2)xubuntu
3) kubuntu
4)gnome shell
5) cinammon
6) mate

The strange fact is that when ive tested lubuntu 12.04 32bits i had tearing but after installing the newest drivers from the xswat repository i didn't had tearing anymore !!
But lubuntu is very elementary desktop its only for the basics dont want it.

Yes i have the latest graphics drivers ubuntu suggests dont bother asking
Yes i've tested download the most updated drivers from xswat repository

I found out that Ati Radeon on their control panel they have an antitearing choice which is working, why nvidia dont have an antitearing choice too ?? what configuration files are altered to stop tearing ??

I dont want to use compiz cause for me it sucks it too heavy without any reason at all.
Gaming with compiz is so so bad less fps less performance , games respond less.
My operating system was ubuntu 12.04 64bit , also i tried so many other distros everywhere tearing.
When i dont use compiz i can play all games in full resolution full detail when compiz is activated gameplay sucks.
I dont care too much about gaming but i hate loosing computer resources for no reason,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used cinammon and i have no tearing anymore !
Plus because i dont use compiz i have full fps on 3d games (on sauerbratten i have 200+fps)
and i can play trine 2 in full resolution 1980x1080 full detail and the games runs very smoothly.